# How to update MySQL two column lookup table where each field is Primary Key

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a lookup table with two fields and each is a PRIMARY KEY. When I attempt to update the table with PHP, it appears to work but doesn't update. The same query (without the prepared part) in phpMyAdmin works fine.

My PHP is:

```
$sql = "UPDATE model_laser SET 
            model_id = :model_id,
            laser_id = :laser_id
            WHERE model_id = :model_id AND laser_id = :laser_id";

$s = $db->prepare($sql);
$s->bindValue(':model_id', $model_id);
$s->bindValue(':laser_id', $laser_id);
$s->execute();
```

phpMyAdmin, using the numbers 1 & 27, gives the php code (this works) as follows:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `model_laser` SET `model_id`= 1,`laser_id`= 27 WHERE model_id = 1 AND laser_id = 17";
```

Thanks for any assistance as to what I'm missing.

Comment: "appears to work" usually means it didn't. did you enable exceptions in PDO? If not, it'll just return a boolean false signifying failure, and you failed to check for that false. `if (!$s->execute()) { die($s->errorInfo); }`

Comment: catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Error updating database.' . $e->getMessage();
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

Comment: Your query statement seems to be fundamentally wrong. You are setting the new values same as the old values so you will never see the update even if it goes through successfully.

Comment: Additionally, the query statement that you are trying in PHPMyAdmin is different than the one in PDO so it seems to be working.

Comment: you also can't reuse placeholder names within a single query. placeholders are `1 value = 1 placeholder` mapping, not `1 value = multiple placeholders`

Comment: @Maximus2012  There are new values. They are coming from a form. The same update code for all other tables in this project works fine. I am setting field values to the holder (:holder) and then binding the values in the posted variables to them. Then executing.

Comment: @MarcB You are correct. How do I write a prepared query that sets the value for field A with X, and the value of field B with Y when A & B are the only fields? I cannot say update A with X and Y with B WHERE id = x. There is no unique ID field. A and B are the PRIMARY KEY fields because it's a lookup table managing a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: bind the same value twice, basically `... set foo=:bar ... where foo=:baz`, and then bind `:bar` and `:baz` to the same `$value`, silly, but that's how it has to be done. placeholders can be thought of as "variables", but they're not re-usable like a real variable would be.

Comment: @MarcB I got it to work! Thank you!  I added two hidden inputs in the form to carry model_id and laser_id data. Then, I posted them as $id and $laser respectively. Then, I wrote the following query:  $sql = "UPDATE model_laser SET 
                model_id = :model_id,
                laser_id = :laser_id
                WHERE model_id = $id AND laser_id = $laser";  Because model_id and laser_id are both PRIMARY KEY fields, I had to use both of them in the WHERE clause. Thank you for taking the time to look at this. The speed of your assessment, diagnosis and prescription was amazing!

Comment: Thank you to each contributor for your input!

Comment: @JimB814: DON'T put variables into your query like that. that opens you up to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). your original query was secure, your new one isn't.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Marc for noting that. I went back and added my sanitation function to the posted data as an sql injection preventative. Thanks again for your help and expertise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be your prepared params. You need to differentiate what you are UPDATING TO from what ALREADY EXISTS in your DB

I think it should look something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE model_laser SET 
        model_id = :new_model_id,
        laser_id = :new_laser_id
        WHERE model_id = :model_id AND laser_id = :laser_id";

$s = $db->prepare($sql);
$s->bindValue(':new_model_id', $new_model_id);
$s->bindValue(':new_laser_id', $new_laser_id);
$s->bindValue(':model_id', $model_id);
$s->bindValue(':laser_id', $laser_id);
$s->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. As noted, I brought the current model_id and laser_id via hidden inputs and posted them as $id and $laser and used them in the WHERE clause. Same result but a slightly different angle than yours. I think I might like yours better because you SET new data to existing fields when you UPDATE. Thanks for taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 0):

Your query has two different numbers for :laser_id. One is 27, one is 17. This could be a typo, or a different problem altogether.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `model_laser` SET `model_id`= 1,`laser_id`= 27 WHERE model_id = 1 AND laser_id = 17";
```

Comment: Thanks, but those numbers are from phpMyAdmin. My data is coming from a form. I used phpMyAdmin to troubleshoot. I have a form that retrieves the database values and displays them. They are changed and then submitted. The same code that works on every other table fails here, and I think it might be related to the fact the it's a lookup table with two fields each of which are PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: If it's working in phpMyAdmin, it's not an issue with trying to update two primary keys. It likely an issue with php. Check your variables and make sure $model_id and $laser_id are actually set properly.

Comment: Thanks. I am checking that now.

Comment: /*----------------  UPDATE MODEL LASER LOOKUP TABLE  --------------*/
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'update_model_laser'){
    
    $table = 'model_laser';
    $model_id = sanitize($_POST['model_id']);
    $laser_id = sanitize($_POST['laser_id']);
    include '../includes/dbconnect.php';
    
    echo '$model_id => ' . $model_id . '<br>';
    echo '$laser_id => ' . $laser_id . '<br>';